# Is it appropriate to ask for the reasons,my job application didn't forwarded to the next stage?

Tags: applications

The last days i have made same job applications to some companies and 2 days ago i received a phone call from the recruit department and we have a small talk about some extra infos, which they need. Everything seemed fine but of course i hold a small bucket (if you know the adage).At the end the lady(recruit department) told me that se will inform me for any changes. And so she did. But the reply was **negative**.

This is **ok**. I know that always are failures in life. Now, i would like to know why i was 'cutted' from them. So my questions now are:

1. Is it correct/appropriate to ask the reasons ?
2. Does this move shows something negative?
3. Will it have any impact in later application to the same company (when i have even more experience)?

Note: In the Requirement section i have 9/10 in what the company was asking to fulfil.

Edit--- 
The question was duplicate, i am sorry for this. But at first i can not find it :/

Comment: You can ask but don't expect anything more than a generic "we already filled the position"

Comment: Hopefully your communication with the company was conducted with more care than your posting here, which is full of issues well beyond those of using a potentially unfamiliar language. Even in a technical field ability to communicate in a professional manner matters.

Comment: @ChrisStratton English isn't necessarily the language the interview / professional communication take place in.

Comment: @dbeer - yes, but the issues here go far beyond language unfamiliarity and are rather those that result from someone who *does not care* about the quality of their communication and who choses far too casual an an approach for professional interaction with those not known to them personally.

Comment: Chris - Ability to communicate and preciseness of communication are two different things.  I understood perfectly what the question was, as I am sure you did too.

Comment: @bushell - I understood it, but even allowing for language unfamiliarity it was *careless* and *unprofessional* - a candidate who did this would have to be technically *stunning* in order to advance.  And a first line interview may not even be with someone able to recognize technical capability, but who only evaluates general worker professionalism.

Comment: I would like to thank all of you,who replied to my question. However, except the "communication part" , you didn't replied to any of my questions except @sf02 . And of course i know that communication matters and moreover i try to improve myself day per day. Anyway! thank you again.

Comment: I'm curious about that bucket. What on earth does your adage mean?

Comment: @TonyK its because of the google translate... i would say in other words "if you know the saying" (i don't know if it exists , in English, at the end ). Translating from one language to another it's not always easy & correct as it seems !!

Comment: Wasn't my question clear? What does it _mean_?

Answer (score 8):

> Is it correct/appropriate to ask the reasons ?

Yes it's appropriate, but often it doesn't give you any real information. In most cases, you'll get a very non-specific response like "we filled the position," but you never know.

> Does this move shows something negative?
>
> Will it have any impact in later application to the same company (when i have even more experience)?

As long as you are polite and professional in asking, it's a slight positive as it shows you really want the job. I have gotten these emails before and never held it against anyone.

Answer (score 5):

I have asked before, phrasing it something like "For my own information going forward, is there an area I am lacking in?".   Don't appear confrontational, or combative in any way if you expect a response, and thank them if they give honest feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much @Keith! i will consider your approach! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can ask, and there's nothing wrong with doing so, but you need to understand that it's basically never in the company's best interests to give you an answer.  They've already decided that they don't want to hire you, so there's nothing to be gained by telling you.  At the same time, companies can be sued if they reject a candidate for an inappropriate reason.  They cannot be sued if they reject a candidate for no reason.  Giving you any reason at all beyond the most blandly generic increases their litigation risk for no gain.

So, they probably won't tell you anything, and when they don't tell you, it'll be because it's the objectively correct thing for them to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask, and it will not have negative (nor positive) impact on future applications. Noone is going to bother attaching a "candidate asked for a reason why he didn't go further" to your file, and if a company is tracking all communication between them and a candidate, noone is going to sift through them to see whether you asked about why you where turned down a previous time.

Having said that, don't expect too much from it. You may get some useful feedback if you made it to the face-to-face interviews; at that stage there's actually a chance people made notes. Earlier stages is more someone going through a pile of applications/resumes and picking a subset out of them for a next round. Notes are not likely to be taken, although you may be lucky if you applied to a small company and there were just a handful of people applying; they may remember your application. But large companies hire hundreds, if not thousands of people a year for a specific role, and for each new employee, they will have rejected 50 to 100 (or more). Even if they can find out who decided not to put you in the "continue to the next round" pile, it's unlikely they remember, or can formulate why they don't continue with you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to get feedback from any interview, as it can only improve your interview skills to find out how it failed, and also if you have any deficiencies you can approach that in time for your next interview.  It's also, baring in mind I interview folk, not frowned upon and see's you in a good light in that you're looking to improve yourself career wise.

Answer (score 1):

As others write, you probably won't get valuable, truthful feedback. You can ask and if it's not a company for complete morons it won't have negative consequences for you. It's just you won't learn anything interesting.

If you don't get further after the first screening, in most companies it's because:

- Your skills don't (seem to) correspond to what is expected
- Your expectations don't correspond to what is offered; e.g. you want to spend the whole days in the office while the position requires traveling
- Your salary expectations don't correspond to what is offered
- You seem not the type of person the company wants to hire; for example, you come across as too shy/ too arrogant/ too proactive/ too lazy...
- You did everything correctly but the position is no longer available, e.g. the CEO's nephew applied or the position was eliminated altogether for financial reasons
- Someone in HR/ hiring unit f*cked up and interviewed you without aligning with the remaining interested parties (HR didn't align with the hiring manager, etc.); then hell broke loose and you are the victim.